# aws secret manager access index

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure-devops, terraform

I am trying to retrieve from aws secret manager key value pairs and pass them to my azure SQL Server. Regarding aws secret manager I am using this module.

```
module "secrets-manager" {
  source  = "lgallard/secrets-manager/aws"
  version = "0.4.1"
  secrets = [
    {
      name = "secretKeyValue"
      description = "Secret Key value pair"
      secret_key_value = {
        username = "username"
        password = "password"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Then I created a azurerm SQL Server and would like to pass the username and password. What I tried is the following code.

```
resource "azurerm_sql_server" "sql-server-testing" {
  administrator_login = module.secrets-manager.secret_ids[0]
  administrator_login_password = module.secrets-manager.secret_ids[0]
  location = "westeurope"
  name = "sql-name"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.azure-secrets.name
  version = "12.0"
}
```

I am able to access the secret manager, but it hit only the amazon arn resource and I can't find a way how to pass the secret username and password to my SQL Server.

Thank you very much for any help you can provide

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1- Retrieve metadata information about a Secrets Manager secret, via [aws secrets manager data resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/secretsmanager_secret_version)

```
data "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "secrets" {
  arn = module.secrets-manager.secret_ids[0]
}

data "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "current" {
  secret_id = data.aws_secretsmanager_secret.secrets.id
}
```

2- Retrieve a specific value inside that secret (in sql code section)

```
administrator_login = jsondecode(data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.current.secret_string)["username"]
administrator_login_password = jsondecode(data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.current.secret_string)["password"]
```

Comment: this is a great post, but you should add some links to the docs for the api's you are referencing!

Comment: Good point : https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/secretsmanager_secret_version

Comment: This is amazing. Thank you so much it works. Just a simple question. Even if this masks my sensitive data from tf file, they still shows up in the tfstate. Is there any way that I can hide the value from tfstate too?

Comment: @NaydenVan No you can't, unless you stop using `aws_secretsmanager_secret_version` in your terraform code.

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65450899/how-can-i-insure-that-my-retrieval-of-secrets-is-secure/65451279#65451279 I already answered this question

Comment: Amazing. Thank you very much guys. You are all amazing.